# Prove or disprove: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(a_{n+1} - \frac 12 a_n\right)=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am stuck on a simple exercise. Let $(a_n)_{_n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Prove or disprove the following statement:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(a_{n+1} - \frac 12 a_n\right)=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0.$$
I tried to prove it directly but didn't make any progress. So I considered proving the contraposition: If you assume $(a_n)_{_{n\in\mathbb N}}$ is a convergent sequence, the contraposition of this statement is easy to prove. Let $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=:a\neq0$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_{n+1} - \frac 12 a_n)=a-\frac a2= \frac a2 \neq 0$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_{n+1} - \frac 12 a_n)=a-\frac a2= \frac a2 \neq 0$. But to correctly prove the contraposition, I also have to consider divergent series. Does $$(a_n)_{_{n\in\mathbb N}}\;divergent \Rightarrow \left( a_{n+1} - \frac 12 a_n \right)_{_{n\in\mathbb N}}\;divergent\; \lor\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(a_{n+1} - \frac 12 a_n\right)\neq0$$ hold? If yes, it would prove the mentioned statement above.

Comment: i upvoted; interesting question, reasonable effort, but wrong track.  i'm too lazy to work it out, but I'll give you a hint that I think will bear fruit.  $a_{(n+1)}$ **is approaching** $(a_n)/2.$  Suppose for a given $\epsilon > 0, N\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ is chosen so that for all $n\geq N, |a_{(n+1)} - (a_n)/2| < \epsilon.$  **To start, make the simplying assumption** that $a_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence.  Form an inequality involving $a_{(n+2)}, a_n,$ and $\epsilon.$  Then form a similary inequality involving $a_{(n+3)}.$  ... see next comment.

Comment: you should be able to extend the inequality indefinitely, showing that $a_{(n+k)}$ must be going to 0.  After doing this you must similarly attack the more general case re the sequence might not be strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 7):

You have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(a_{n + 1} - \frac{1}{2}a_n\right) = 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This means that, by the definition of limits, for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there's an integer $n_0$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ you have

$$\left|a_{n + 1} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_n\right| \lt \epsilon \implies -\epsilon \lt a_{n+1} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_n \lt \epsilon \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The procedure below is somewhat similar to what [user2661923](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464411/user2661923)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625907/prove-or-disprove-lim-n-to-infty-lefta-n1-frac-12-a-n-right-0-rig/3625947#comment7452538_3625907) suggests, which I read while I was writing this answer. In addition, as stated in the comment, I also don't see any way offhand to finish the proof using contraposition as you tried.

For $n = n_{0}$, \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$-\epsilon \lt a_{n_{0} + 1} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_{n_{0}} \lt \epsilon \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Next, for $n = n_{0} + 1$, you also have

$$-\epsilon \lt a_{n_{0} + 2} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_{n_{0} + 1} \lt \epsilon \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Multiplying all $3$ parts of \eqref{eq3A} by $\frac{1}{2}$ and adding the results to \eqref{eq4A} gives

$$-\left(1 + \frac{1}{2}\right)\epsilon \lt a_{n_{0} + 2} - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)a_{n_{0}} \lt \left(1 + \frac{1}{2}\right)\epsilon \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Now, for $n = n_0 + 2$, \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$-\epsilon \lt a_{n_{0} + 3} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)a_{n_{0} + 2} \lt \epsilon \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Multiplying all $3$ parts of \eqref{eq5A} by $\frac{1}{2}$ and adding the results to \eqref{eq6A} gives

$$-\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\right)\epsilon \lt a_{n_{0} + 3} - \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)a_{n_{0}} \lt \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\right)\epsilon \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

You can repeat this procedure $k$ times to get

$$-2\epsilon \lt -\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2^{i}}\right)\epsilon \lt a_{n_0 + k} - \left(\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right)a_{n_0} \lt \left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{2^{i}}\right)\epsilon \lt 2\epsilon \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

This can be fairly easily proven, e.g., by induction, which I'll leave to you to do.

Next, choose a $k_{0}$ large enough so that $\left|\left(\frac{1}{2^{k_0}}\right)a_{n_0}\right| \lt \epsilon$, e.g., $k_{0} = 1$ if $a_{n_0} = 0$, else $k_0 = \max(\left\lfloor\log_{2}{|a_{n_0}|} - \log_{2}{\epsilon}\right\rfloor + 1, 1)$. Then, since $\left|\left(\frac{1}{2^{k_0}}\right)a_{n_0}\right|$ is a non-negative decreasing function in $k_{0}$ for all $k \ge k_{0}$, you have

$$-3\epsilon \lt a_{n_0 + k} \lt 3\epsilon \implies \left|a_{n_0 + k}\right| \lt 3\epsilon \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

I trust you can finish the rest of the proof to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0 \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

Comment: (8) also implies $-2\epsilon \leq \liminf a_n \leq \limsup a_n \leq 2 \epsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$, which imo leads to a cleaner ending

Answer (score 3):

We prove the following general claim, since doing so does not harm the essence of the idea:

> **Tauberian Theorem for Nørlund means.** Let $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ be sequences such that
>
> 1. $b_n > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $\frac{b_n}{b_1 + \cdots + b_n} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
> 2. $c_n \to \ell$ as $n\to\infty$ for some $\ell$.
>
> Then we have
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_1 c_n + b_2 c_{n-1} + \cdots + b_n c_1}{b_1 + \cdots + b_n} = \ell. $$

Before proving this theorem, we check that this indeed implies the desired claim. Choose

$$b_n = 2^{1-n} \qquad\text{and} \qquad c_n = a_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2}a_n.$$

If $c_n$ converges to some limit $\ell$, then

$$ \frac{a_{n+1} - 2^{-n}a_1}{2 - 2^{-n}} = \frac{b_1 c_n + b_2 c_{n-1} + \cdots + b_n c_1}{b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \ell = 0. $$

This implies that $a_n \to 2\ell$ as $n\to\infty$. In OP's case, we have $\ell = 0 $ and therefore the desired conclusion follows.

---

*Proof of Theorem.* Fix an arbitrary $N \geq 1$. Then for any $n \geq N$,

\begin{align*}
&\left| \frac{b_1 c_n + b_2 c_{n-1} + \cdots + b_n c_1}{b_1 + \cdots + b_n} - \ell \right| \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{b_{n+1-k}}{b_1+\cdots+b_n} |c_k - \ell| \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{b_{n+1-k}}{b_1+\cdots+b_n} |c_k - \ell| + \biggl( \sup_{k > N} |c_k - \ell| \biggr) \sum_{k=N+1}^{n} \frac{b_{n+1-k}}{b_1+\cdots+b_n} \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{b_{n+1-k}}{b_1+\cdots+b_{n+1-k}} |c_k - \ell| +\sup_{k > N} |c_k - \ell|.
\end{align*}

Taking $\limsup$ as $n\to\infty$, the first sum in the last step converges to $0$ since each of the $N$ terms converges to $0$. So we obtain a bound

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{b_1 c_n + b_2 c_{n-1} + \cdots + b_n c_1}{b_1 + \cdots + b_n} - \ell \right| \leq \sup_{k > N} |c_k - \ell|. $$

But since the left-hand side is independent of $N$, letting $N\to\infty$ shows that the limsup is in fact zero. This implies the desired convergence. $\square$

Comment: +1 for letting us know a general result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \varepsilon >0 \cdot $

There exists some $ n_{1}\in\mathbb{N} $ such that $ \left(\forall n\geq n_{1}\right),\ \left|a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{n}\right|<\varepsilon \cdot $

And we have for every $ n> n_{1} $ :

\begin{aligned} \left|a_{n}\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1-k}}\left(a_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{k}\right)}+\frac{a_{0}}{2^{n}}\right|\\ \leq\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1-k}}\left|a_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{k}\right|}+\frac{\left|a_{0}\right|}{2^{n}}\ \ \ &=\sum_{k=0}^{n_{0}-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1-k}}\left|a_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{k}\right|}+\sum_{k=n_{0}}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1-k}}\left|a_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{k}\right|}+\frac{\left|a_{0}\right|}{2^{n}}\\ &\leq\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n_{0}-1}{2^{k+1}\left|a_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2^{k}}a_{k}\right|}+\varepsilon\sum_{k=n_{0}}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1-k}}}+\frac{\left|a_{0}\right|}{2^{n}} \end{aligned}

Since $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n_{0}-1}{2^{k+1}\left|a_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2^{k}}a_{k}\right|} $ and $ \left|a_{0}\right| $ aren't depending of $ n $, we have : $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{1}{2^{n}}\left(\left|a_{0}\right|+\sum_{k=0}^{n_{0}-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1-k}}\left|a_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{k}\right|}\right)}=0 $, thus there exists some $ n_{2} $ such that $$ \left(\forall n\geq n_{1}\right),\ \frac{1}{2^{n}}\left(\left|a_{0}\right|+\sum_{k=0}^{n_{0}-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1-k}}\left|a_{k+1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{k}\right|}\right)<\varepsilon $$

Hence, for every $ n> \max\left(n_{1},n_{2}\right) $, we have : $$ \left|a_{n}\right|<\varepsilon +\varepsilon\sum_{k=n_{0}}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^{n-1-k}}}=\varepsilon\left(3-2^{n_{0}-n+1}\right)\leq 3\varepsilon $$

Thus : $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}{a_{n}}=0 $$